# How many significant figures for an arithmetic mean?

Tags: arithmetic, significant-figures

I am doing an analysis of a group of health centers scattered through a city. I'm trying to find, for a group of zip codes, how many of the health centers are within 5 miles of each zip code; then, I want to take an average. I'd like to say, for example, "On average, there are N centers within 5 miles of a given zip code in group A, and K within 5 miles of those in group B."

My question is, if (for example) in a group of 5 zip codes I come up with 3, 2, 0, 1, and 1 "nearby" centers, should I say that there are on average 1.4 centers near a given zip code, or should I say that there is 1?

Answer (score 2):

Owing to the rules of significant figures, since the fraction you'd get is $7/5$, with the $5$ as a given constant, you'd go to a precision of one place.

Thus, it'd be $1$ instead of $1.4$.

Though personally, this doesn't seem like the kind of problem that you'd use significant figures for, since significant figures are primarily meant to contend with inaccuracies and human errors in measurement. But I'll assume you know more about the context of this problem than I do.

Comment: The reason I was asking actually has a bit less to do with significant figures than with the application - it seemed odd to me to say that "on average there are 1.4 centers near the zip code". Perhaps I should think of it as "the average number of centers near the zip code is 1.4"?

Comment: Personally both are equivalent, so I guess whichever phrasing makes sense to you. I just have kinda learned through experience that averages don't mean it's necessarily exact, i.e. you wouldn't see $1.4$ centers anywhere because what in the world is $0.4$ of a center? You'd just see mostly $1$ or $2$, maybe sometimes $0$ or $3$ rarely, depending on the distribution - that's basically what the statement "$1.4$ centers on average" means. So I think you're just kinda overthinking it and it seems perfectly natural to say there's an average of $1.4$ centers.